# Is this a valid url?

Tags: url

My question below is:

Is this a valid URL?

https://example.com/css/login.css?12.1

My questions is basically is the "." ok in 12.1 for the query string?

Comment: The official URI syntax is at http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986, for those that care to know exactly which characters must be url-encoded and when.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is.

> In essence this means that the only characters you can reliably use
>   for the actual name parts of a URL are a-z, A-Z, 0-9, -, ., _, and ~.
>   Any other characters need to be Percent encoded.

[Source](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201008/what_characters_are_allowed_unencoded_in_query_strings/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes Correct Url.Please Go Through the official URL validation criteria over this https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.